# Signal alarm does not raise error

Tags: python, python-2.7, signals

In the following code, I'm trying to create a class 'TimedExecutor' which would stop the execution of the function(bar) passed to its method 'execute' if exceeds a certain time limit. But, the program execution doesn't stop, even though the error message is displayed.

Note: We must not make any changes to the function `bar()`, as it is provided by an external module.

```
import signal
import time

class MyError(Exception):
  """Base error"""

class MyInheritedError(MyError):
  """Class to inherit from base error"""


class TimeoutListener(object):
  def __init__(self, timeout_seconds, error_message="Timeout executing."):
    self.timeout_seconds = timeout_seconds
    self.error_message = error_message
    self.alarm = None

  def __enter__(self):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, self._handle_timeout)
    signal.alarm(self.timeout_seconds)

  def __exit__(self, listener_type, value, traceback):
    # Disable the alarm.
    if self.alarm:
      self.alarm = None
    else:
      signal.alarm(0)

  def _handle_timeout(self, signum, frame):
    print("Got the signum %s with frame: %s" % (signum, frame))
    raise MyInheritedError(self.error_message + "aditya")


class TimedExecutor(object):
  @staticmethod
  def execute(timeout_secs, functor, *args, **kwargs):
    msg = "Timeout executing method - %s." % functor.__name__
    timeout_signal = TimeoutListener(timeout_secs, error_message=msg)
    try:
      with timeout_signal:
        output = functor(*args, **kwargs)
    except MyInheritedError as ex:
      print("%s did not complete in %s: %s."
            % (functor.__name__, timeout_secs, repr(ex)))
      raise
    return output


def bar():
  for _ in range(5):
    try:
      time.sleep(1)
      print("SLEEPING")
    except MyInheritedError as ex:
      print ex


ob = TimedExecutor.execute(2, bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your functor is swallowing the exception you intend to be fatal.

It is `bar()`'s *except* clause in one of its loops that prints and then discards the error raised by the  `TimeoutListener` context manager.  Then the loop resumes.

`bar()` should probably not be aware of the exception your `TimedExecutor` can raise.  Instead, `bar()`'s caller who invokes `.execute()` should be aware of it:

```
from aditya.utils import TimedExecutor, TimeoutException

...

try:
  TimedExecutor.execute(2, bar)
except TimeoutException:
  print("Timed out executing bar")
```

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work too. Could you provide a working code?

Comment: The solution is merely to remove the try/except block from within `bar()`.  What I presented was a pseudocode refactor.

Comment: No, the function bar() cannot be changed, it comes from another module. I need to design a code which handles the timing out of the execution.

Comment: Then can you change `TimedExecutor` and `TimeoutListener` to throw an exception that is unknown to `bar()`?  That would have the same effect.

Comment: Yes, we can do that, but what if `bar()` is using `Exception`? All other error classes are inherited from exception

Comment: I think you have a different question now:  how do I interrupt a codeblock that tries hard to be uninterruptible?